# Deep link to text file in Azure Data Lake Store

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I am trying to quickly access text files via URL. The Azure portal (http://portal.azure.com) can (at best) link to the explore view of a specific folder, but I have not found any way to deep link into a specific file.

I also tried Azure Storage Explorer, which *does* support adl:// URLs but (apart from opening slowly) it only browses to the folder and it doesn't actually open it.

My use case is that at the end of each data processing job, I want to print a URL to open a text file for browsing.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact , there's no anonymous access allowed for files stored in ADLS. The access needs to be authorized so that we can't open it via the url directly.

Based on your situation, I suggest you creating your own endpoint (For example: [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/)) as proxy to access resources with being authorized. You could access Azure Function with the url of the file you want to open as parameter.Then make the request to get the content of the file to display for browsing.

In addition, considering the security of accessing files , you need to focus on the [Access control in Azure Data Lake Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control#access-control-lists-on-files-and-folders).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. In this case I assume the user is already logged in to the azure portal and also the azure CLI.

Comment: @aaronsteers You want to view the content in the portal directly?

Comment: If possible, yes.

Comment: @aaronsteers Not supported yet.You could submit feedback to microsoft about your requirements.

Comment: @aaronsteers Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It doesn't solve my problem but sounds like what I want to do is not possible. As an alternative, it would even be helpful to be able to deep link into a USQL job - since that page has a tab for the file outputs. Not having this just means it's terribly cumbersome: (1) to share my results with others, and (2) to toggle between the programmatic API and the web console. In both cases, it takes several clicks, scrolls, page-turns and more click just to view a friendly Html output page of a job - whether it be the USQL job page or the data lake file/folder output itself.

Comment: @aaronsteers Thanks for your sharing.